# Will a new keychain be synchronized over iCloud?

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, keychain

If I create a new personal Keychain, in this example I called "Test", everything I save into my new "Test" goes to my iCloud too? Or remain just local into my computer?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This keychain will remain local. Only keys/certs/etc in the iCloud Keychain will be synchronised over iCloud.